# Persist OneToMany associated in Symfony 4.1 with Doctrine

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm, symfony4

I try to persist data I got in my entity with OneToMany association.

With FOS REST Bundle I get the entity in the controller.

```
public function add(Campaign $campaign)
{
    $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
    $em->persist($campaign);
    $em->flush();
```

My entities are:

```
class Campaign
{
/**
 * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="App\Entity\CampaignDates",
 *     mappedBy="campaign", cascade={"persist"})
 */
private $dates;

public function addDate(CampaignDates $date): self
{
    if (!$this->dates->contains($date)) {
        $this->dates[] = $date;
        $date->setCampaign($this);
    }

    return $this;
}

class CampaignDates
{
  /**
   * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="App\Entity\Campaign", 
  inversedBy="dates")
   */
  private $campaign;

public function getCampaign(): ?Campaign
{
    return $this->campaign;
}

public function setCampaign(?Campaign $campaign): self
{
    $this->campaign = $campaign;

    return $this;
}
```

In the Database the id in campaign_dates table that associated to campaign is empty.

Comment: Can you show the code for the `setCampaign` function in your `CampaignDates` entity?

Comment: I just update with the setter and getter.

Comment: Just to rule out the obvious, are you actually calling the `add` function (where you persist `campaign`)? You might also look in the symfony debug trace to verify your database is being updated the way you expect with appropriate sql statements.

Comment: I use SensioFrameworkExtraBundle to convert the json to the object before persist and flush. I discovered if I just build the entities. like new Campaign()... and then persist that it works fine. So I assume it's with the Param conversion and the bundle, but when I check the value using the Debugger I don't see any difference. so wonder if the cascade persist isn't done when persist and flush?

Answer (score 0):

Try this command:

```
php bin/console doctrine:schema:validate

OR

php bin/console d:s:v
```

Answer (score 0):

Did you try : php bin/console doctrine:migrations:diff and after php bin/console doctrine:migrations:migrate . 
When you do that it create automaticaly addCampaign() and removeCampaign()

Comment: I got setCampaign generated when I created the entity with bin/console make:entity

Answer (score 0):

The only way I found at the moment to solve the issue, which I don't think is great is to create again the associated entities.
My code looks like that

```
    $dates = $campaign->getDates();
    if ($dates) {
        foreach ($dates as $date) {
            $dateObj = new CampaignDates();
            $dateObj->setDate($date->getDate())->setName($date->getName());
            $campaign->removeDate($date);
            $campaign->addDate($dateObj);
        }
    }
    $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
    $em->persist($campaign);
    $em->flush();
```

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure but it is working for symfony 2.6.
Change you setCampaign to this

```
public function setCampaign(?Campaign $campaign): self {
    $this->campaign = $campaign;
    $campaign->addDate($date);
    return $this;
}
```

You can check this.
[Symfony Doctrine One to Many does not insert foreign key](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28135863/symfony-doctrine-one-to-many-does-not-insert-foreign-key)

Comment: I'm going to update the Question as it doesn't work when using the ParamConverter with FOS Rest Bundle and Framework Extra Bundle. I wrote it in the comment. Just like that it worked for me as well. even without  $campaign->addDate($date); also you got an error as $date is never set in your function.